# How to make bootstrap rows while going through a list in react and making elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is how I am currently doing it - it is very uneloquent, and it doesn't work. I am getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at grid.push(<Card key={index+x} name={list[index+x][0]} img={list[index+x][1]}/>);
```

this is my code

```
const list = // my list of data
        var grid = [];
        list.map((element, index) => {
            if (index%4 == 0) {
                if (index<list.length-2) {
                const el = (<div className="row">
                //card being a component I built
                <Card key={index} name={element[0]} img={element[1]}/>
                <Card key={index+1} name={list[index+1][0]} img={list[index+1][1]}/>
                <Card key={index+2} name={list[index+2][0]} img={list[index+2][1]}/>
                <Card key={index+3} name={list[index+3][0]} img={list[index+3][1]}/>
                </div>)
                grid.push(el);
                } else {
                    let remainder = (list.length-index);
                    for (var x=0;x+=1;x<remainder) {
                        grid.push(<Card key={index+x} name={list[index+x][0]} img={list[index+x][1]}/>);
                    }
                }

            }
        })\
        return (
        <div>
            {grid}
        </div>
        )
```

The current way I am doing it is making grid then iterating through the list and adding jsx to it. The problem is that I need to make a row for bootstrap every 4 columns to make the grid, any better ideas, solutions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the data in list variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using index+1, index+2, index+3 which will never exist in the array, when you reach last element.
Instead calculate it in some other variable to find elements which exist.

Comment: the bigger problem is that I need to make bootstrap rows every 4 but I want to just iterate through and make a card for each. I kinda do what you are talking about where I calculate the remainder and push cards onto the grid

Comment: You can just add a row outside and iterate through list with col-md-3

list.map((element, index) => {
  const el = (
  <div className="col-md-3">
    <Card key={index} name={list[index][0]} img={list[index][1]}/>
  </div>)
  grid.push(el);
})
<div className="col-md-12">
            {grid}
        </div>

Comment: thanks, the solution was to stop the crazy algorithm and just loop through and add it!